# Python importing and code structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance, structure

I have Two questions to ask about my Python code, please excuse if they are newbie questions, i am still relatively new to certain areas of programming.

Ok so i am writing my own library for a certain web application and after watching a brilliant presentation on the overuse of OOP (unfortunately the name escapes me) i refactored all my code, removing what i felt where unused classes and making my code much more easier on the eye and easier to maintain. My main question is on the code structure, i currently have a file called Client containing a class, but after realising this may become huge in time, i wrote a seperate class called BaseRequests, which might be needlessly small. My first question is, is it better to have a lot of smaller, little classes e.g. BaseRequests as well as Client or create a rather large class e.g. Client.

My second question is more non-specific but still based on the same structure area, so i want my library to be able to be used as follows:

```
import Module
client = Module.Client()
```

But how would that work if i have multiple different classes (like the BaseRequests one), that i don't want a normal user to have to specifically declare as a object. It just dawned on me that Inheritance may be an option, am i right in thinking so? And if so, can a class inherit from multiple other classes, and is this good practise?

Comment: Is BaseRequests used by client?

Comment: Yeah, some of the methods in BaseRequests would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can instantiate BaseRequests inside the Client class and use it there. WRT your first question, look up the programming paradigm "separation of concerns". Basically a class, interface, factory or any other structure should only be concerned with doing one thing. So a Client class should only be concerned with acting as a client, and not doing other things like say... printing log messages to a file. You would make a separate logger class for that (use python's built in one)

Comment: Thank you for the answer sir, it was very helpful. Accepted due to it answering my questions.

Comment: np :D glad to help